# Secured Azure Mobile Services in .NET - How to get userId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services .NET Backend (v1.0348) with a Custom Authentication Provider which is working perfectly.  I have a WebAPI service that I am protecting with the AuthorizationLevel.User attribute.

I can login successfully against the Custom Authentication Provider.  I can pass the auth token (X-ZUMO-AUTH) header for each subsequent request and it works fine (it allows a user with a valid auth token in the header to access the protected services in the WebAPI).

From the WebAPI service, how do I get the Username of the user?  How can I use the X-ZUMO-AUTH header to get at the authenticated user's Username?

On my ApiController class (decorated with AuthorizationLevel.User), I was expecting this would work:  this.User.Identity.GetUserId()  or even this.User.Identity.Name

That seems intuitive, right?  No such luck.  Doesn't work.  It returns an empty string.

The documentation on this is very weak/non-existent.  I'm hunting and pecking, but no luck.

Dan

Comment: Are you using JS-Backed Mobile service?

Comment: for JS-backed, i have used `client.currentUser.userId` and it works. May be you can try something in .net.

Comment: I figured it out.  

var myUser = User as ServiceUser;
var userId = myUser.Id;

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

var myUser = User as ServiceUser;

var userId = myUser.Id;